# Using objects to correctly replace global variables

Tags: javascript, html, object

I've been trying to figure out how to initialize an object using a prototype in order to escape using global variables, which I first learned about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190792/should-i-use-a-global-variable-and-if-not-what-instead-javascript). I began implementing my own version of the code found in the accepted answer.

```
function XML_Data() {
  this.data = null;
}

XML_Data.prototype = {
 GetXML: function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "questions.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
    this.data=xml;
   } //close success
  });//close AJAX  
 },

 UseXML: function() {
  alert(this.data)
 }
};
```

*(My implementation of the script)*

---

However, I've run into a problem. When I run the functions shown here by using this bit of code:

```
var data = new XML_Data();
data.GetXML();
data.UseXML();
```

I get an alert that says "null". I've been through the code about a dozen times, but as this is my first time working with Javascript, there's quite obviously something I've missed. Could you point that out?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville.

Comment: Do you want to use the Ajax data immediately? How often do you get new data via Ajax?

Comment: Just once, at the beginning of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just of note

```
var data = new XML_Data();
data.GetXML();  //This will run the ajax request
data.UseXML();  //This will most likely run before the ajax request is finished.
```

Publishing events in Jquery would problably work,but I havent tested this code.

```
function XML_Data() {
  this.data = null;
}

XML_Data.prototype = {
 GetXML: function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
      url: "questions.xml",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(xml) {
    this.data=xml;
    $(window).trigger("myAjaxEvent");
   } //close success
  });//close AJAX  
 },

 UseXML: function() {
  alert(this.data)
 }
};


$(document).ready( function () {
    var data = new XML_Data();
    $(window).bind("myAjaxEvent", function () {
      data.UseXML();
    });

    data.GetXML();

});
```

Comment: Is that so? How would I fix that?

Comment: @Elliot ... you could try publishing events using jquery

Answer (score 0):

The code you have now is attempting to run synchronously (in order) using a non-blocking asynchronous API. The UseXML call happens before the GetXML call actually finishes doing its AJAX thing, because it's asynchronous.

You could write this in an asynchronous pattern (in which this.UseXML is called directly on success of the AJAX request), or a synchronous pattern (in which "async:false" is passed to the AJAX call). The asynchronous pattern is much more common in JavaScript development, as it is much more powerful, and synchronous requests block the UI in the browser by preventing script execution, but synchronous is much easier to do for little things.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/