# HTMLBOX set_text adding inner text areas, get_text not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have seen other questions similar to this on StackOverflow, but the answer was not very helpful, so i am posting this again.

Htmlbox text area documentation is not very helpful and there is not much help anywhere, so I am asking here.

1 . Set_text
I tried setting text dynamically on my htmlbox text area and it is creating new text areas within the rich text area, for every new text added.

I tried different things like:

```
$("#textArea").htmlbox().set_text("Hello");      
$("#textArea").htmlbox({}).set_text("Hello");
```

or

```
var textArea =  $("#textArea").htmlbox();
textArea.set_text("Hello");
```

All do the same thing, but they are the options suggested on Stack overflow.

2 . Get_text 
 Also how to I retrieve the html text like `<font size="2">Hello</font>` from the Htmltext box. I tried `$("#textBox").htmlbox().get_text()`, but it is giving a popup saying

```
This rich text component is not supported by your browser.
TypeError: iframe.contentWindow is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer to my question. I needed to declare the textArea variable globally in the javascript file, as it was rendering the text area every time it is being instantiated. Now both set and get are working fine.

Also this worked with FF, but IE was throwing an error saying innerHTML : null or undefined. This is because IE does not work well with global variables. The solution to this problem is declaring a namespace in my javascript file and adding all my functions and variables in the namespace. Got help from here

[Should I use a global variable and if not, what instead? (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190792/should-i-use-a-global-variable-and-if-not-what-instead-javascript?rq=1)